# Hyperlink is not working for images

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink

I am trying to make a link from an image , means after clicking an image I would like to redirect to another site . I have used the following

```
<div class="haus">
    <a href="http://google.com"><img src="http://schwedenladen.de/wp-content/themes/schweden/style/img/haus_icon.png" alt="Haus"></a>
</div>
```

CSS CODE

```
.haus {
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 50px;
    padding: 0 0 5px;
    width: 30px;
    border:1px solid red;
    z-index:999;
}
```

I am not getting the hyper link icon , when I move mouse over the image

Comment: Seems to work for me when I make an html file. Can you show us the css for the div class?

Comment: Thanks for your valuable advice . I have updated the css code of the div 'haus', but it is not working now. I have highlighted the portion with red color

Comment: I have added the css code in question

Comment: `z-index` is only a number it has no unit, get rid of the `px`

Comment: You need to stop linking to live sites in your question. This defeats the purpose of Stack Overflow. As soon as you fix your problem, the question contains a link that is no longer useful in reproducing the problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your image is BEHIND the banner. Try this:

```
.haus>a {
     position: absolute;
     z-index: 9999;
 }
```

The z-index is important, since the header has a very high value that needs to be sent to back.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable advice . I have updated the css code of the div 'haus', but it is not working now. I have highlighted the portion with red color

Comment: try the following: .haus>a {position: absolute;z-index: 9999;}

Comment: I'd explain a bit my suggestion. The div "haus" is constrained by the header, and all we need to have in the front is the element "a". That's why I suggest to use a restrictive CSS selector, to avoid side effects in other elements in the website.

Comment: You have put 999px instead of 999 on your site PX is not needed